# Select inputs in first row of table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have page that I'm working on that contains a table with a header row, several rows of text inputs, and a total row. When a user enters numbers in the inputs, the sum of each column is calculated in the totals row. This calculation is run when an input's `change()` event is fired.

When the page is loaded, I'd like to be able to trigger a `change()` event on the text inputs in the first row of the table. I'm having some trouble figuring out the correct selector to use.

Exampe of table structure:

```
<table>
  <tr class="tblRow headerRow">
    <!-- header cells -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="altTblRow">
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input1-1">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input1-2">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input1-3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tblRow">
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input2-1">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input2-2">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input2-3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tblRow">
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input3-1">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input3-2">
    </td>
    <td class="tableCell">
      <input type="text" id="input3-3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="altTblRow totalRow">
    <!-- total cells -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried using a couple of selectors, but haven't been able to get what I'm looking for.

```
$('.tblRow:first input').change();
$('.tblRow input').first().change();
$('.tblRow input').parent('tr').find('input').change();
```

Is there a selector that I can use for just the inputs in the first table row, or do I have to get the first `input` and get the row using `.parent()`?

*(Note: ID's have been changed in the code sample; otherwise I'd use `'input[class*=input1]'`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, though untested:

```
$('tr:not(".headerRow")').first().find('input').change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pSZxG/2/).

Further, though, I'd suggest reworking your HTML to take advantage of semantics (Which will simplify your jQuery):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="tblRow headerRow">
      <!-- header cells -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="altTblRow totalRow">
      <!-- total cells -->
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="altTblRow">
      <td class="tableCell">
        <input type="text" id="input1-1">
      </td>
      <td class="tableCell">
        <input type="text" id="input1-2">
      </td>
      <td class="tableCell">
        <input type="text" id="input1-3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- other rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which would allow you to simply use:

```
$('tbody tr').first().find('input').change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pSZxG/3/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

Insetead of using table row try While(parameter)and try it and than see what result you are getting if you get clear tell me if not show me the exact error what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You could select all rows except the last one:

```
$('tr:not(:last-child) input')
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/unavux/1/edit)

Or if you want header neither:

```
$('tr:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) input')
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I'm trying to select only the inputs in one row, because the table will end up having a couple hundred cells (something like a 15 x 25 table) and I don't want to bog down the page with many calculations if I just run one per column. It might, however, work to use `$('tr:not(:last-child):not(:first-child).first().find('input)`. I'll give it a shot.